# Ant and Jacoco: Need to set junit's fork to "true" but not property that's true

Tags: ant, junit, jacoco

I'm using the Jacoco Junit task and tried the following:

```
    <!-- run the junit tests -->
    <echo>DEBUG: $${junit.fork} = "${junit.fork}"</echo>
    <jacoco:coverage
        destfile="${target.dir}/jacoco.exec"
        append="false">
        <junit fork="${junit.fork}" includeAntRuntime="true">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement path="${main.destdir}"/>
                <pathelement path="${test.destdir}"/>
            </classpath>
            <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
            <formatter type="${junit.formatter.type}"/>
            <batchtest      todir="${junit.batchtest.todir}">
                <fileset dir="${test.destdir}" />
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </jacoco:coverage>
```

And got the following:

```
test:
     [echo] DEBUG: ${junit.fork} = "true"
[jacoco:coverage] Enhancing junit with coverage

BUILD FAILED
D:\build.xml:233: Coverage can only be applied on a forked VM

Total time: 6 seconds

D:\>
```

As you can see, `${junit.fork}` property was set to `true`, and I used that property in `<junit fork="${junit.fork}"/>`.

However, instead of using that property, I simply set `<junit fork="true">`, it works fine:

```
    <jacoco:coverage
        destfile="${target.dir}/jacoco.exec"
        append="false">
        <junit fork="true" includeAntRuntime="true">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement path="${main.destdir}"/>
                <pathelement path="${test.destdir}"/>
            </classpath>
            <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
            <formatter type="${junit.formatter.type}"/>
            <batchtest      todir="${junit.batchtest.todir}">
                <fileset dir="${test.destdir}" />
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </jacoco:coverage>
```

I have run `ant -d test` to verify that the Java JVM is forking when I use the `${junit.fork}` property.

Why is JaCoCo insisting that the JUnit test isn't being forked unless I set the `fork` parameter to the string `true` and not to a property that's equals `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Jacoco coverage task source code](https://eclemma.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/eclemma/jacoco/trunk/org.jacoco.ant/src/org/jacoco/ant/CoverageTask.java) :

```
...
public void enhanceTask(final Task task) {
    final RuntimeConfigurable configurableWrapper = task.getRuntimeConfigurableWrapper();

    final String forkValue = (String) configurableWrapper.getAttributeMap().get("fork");
    if (!Project.toBoolean(forkValue)) {
        throw new BuildException("Coverage can only be applied on a forked VM", getLocation());
    }
    addJvmArgs(task);
}
...
```

The forkValue is read from the configurableWrapper. The attribute map values (like `${junit.fork}`) are evalutated using the method `RuntimeConfigurable.maybeConfigure` which is invoked by `Task.mayBeConfigure`. And when you continue to look at the Jacoco source code  :

```
...
public void addTask(final Task task) {
    if (childTask != null) {
        throw new BuildException("Only one child task can be supplied to the coverge task", getLocation());
    }
    this.childTask = task;
    final String subTaskTypeName = task.getTaskType();
    final TaskEnhancer enhancer = findEnhancerForTask(subTaskTypeName);
    if (enhancer == null) {
        throw new BuildException(format("%s is not a valid child of the coverage task", subTaskTypeName), getLocation());
}
    if (isEnabled()) {
        log(format("Enhancing %s with coverage", childTask.getTaskName()));
        enhancer.enhanceTask(task);
    }
    task.maybeConfigure();
}
...
```

This method (`mayBeConfigure`) is invoked after the task has been enhanced (`enhancer.enhanceTask(task);`).
I guess that it is your problem and a bug... and we should report it to the jacoco bug tracker.

[Jacoco issue](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/eclemma/ticket/213)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not really a Java developer, so it took me a while to see what you were saying. Still not 100% sure, but at least I know what I was seeing isn't an issue on my part, and wasn't expected behavior. I'll report the bug, and link to your answer.